# How Can i find date in string c#

Tags: c#, regex, date

Can you advice me, how solve the problem

I need get date from string.

For example:

```
Dear client come to our shop 20.08.2014 10:20 other text
```

or

```
Dear client come to our shop 20 august 2014 10:20 other text
```

Thanks.

Comment: You  can find useful info on where to start coding in the tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: This string comes by mixing some code or you have it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the date pattern to extract it from the string

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/12)

For second pattern use

```
\d{2} (january|february|march|...) \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
(?i)\d{1,2}\s*\.?\s*(?:\d{1,2}|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s*\.?\s*\d{2,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement your custom implementation as ypur requirements is very different.

use c# built-in functions and implement your logic

1. String.IndexOf    (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. String.Substring   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note: Handle 12 months 30 days and an year with there different formats and get the substring based on that.